# Webscraping-Python loop stuck

Tags: python-3.x, loops, web-scraping

This is just a normal program to scrape top 250 movies on imdb. But when I try to go to the links of each individual movie to get more info, the loop gets stuck.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website="https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/"
d={}
r=requests.get(website, headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 
10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"})
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")

all=soup.find_all("td",{"class": "titleColumn"})

for item in all:
    d["Name"]=item.find("a").text
    #print(d["Name"])
    d["Links"]="https://www.imdb.com"+item.find("a").get("href")
    #print(d["Links"])
    r2=requests.get(d["Links"], headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac 
    OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 
    Safari/537.36"})
    c2=r2.content
    soup2=BeautifulSoup(c2, "html.parser")
    d["Info"]=soup2.find("div", class=False)
    print(d["Info"])
```

Can we not scrape multiple web pages at once?
I am using jupyter notebooks.

I was trying to get movie summary. but then realised that the loop is stuck at this statement (used the print statement to find this)

Comment: so what is it that you want? what is it that you are having problem with? what output you are getting? what output you want? please keep this in mind before posting any questions so that others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why your loop gets stuck but it looks like you have a syntax error with `class=False`, at least this is what my IDE says. Anyhow, you can scrape multiple pages but in order to do that you need to get the urls first.

Here's a working example that builds a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

`[{url: movie_url, title: movie_title, summary: movie_summary}]`

The code:

```
import csv

import requests
import unicodedata

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_movie_urls(main_url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/") -> list:
    r = requests.get(main_url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
    titles = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "titleColumn"})
    return [f"https://imdb.com{title.find('a').get('href')}" for title in titles]


def get_movie_info(url: str) -> dict:
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    title_wrapper = s.find("div", {"class": "title_wrapper"}).find("h1")
    summary = s.find("div", {"class": "summary_text"})
    title = title_wrapper.text.strip().split('(')[0].rstrip()
    return {
        "url": url,
        "title": unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", title),
        "summary": summary.text.strip(),
    }


def scrape_imdb(limit: int = 0) -> list:
    return [get_movie_info(url) for url in get_movie_urls()[:limit]]


def dump_to_csv(imdb_data: list):
    keys = imdb_data[0].keys()
    with open('imdb_top250.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, keys)
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerows(imdb_data)


data = scrape_imdb(limit=2)
print(data)
dump_to_csv(data)
```

This outputs:

```
[{'url': 'https://imdb.com/title/tt0111161/', 'title': 'The Shawshank Redemption', 'summary': 'Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.'}, {'url': 'https://imdb.com/title/tt0068646/', 'title': 'The Godfather', 'summary': 'The aging patriarch of an organized crime dynasty transfers control of his clandestine empire to his reluctant son.'}]
```

To scrape all 250 top movies, just remove the limit argument from `scrape_imdb(limit=2)` to have just `scrape_imdb()`.

As a bonus, I've added dumping the results to a `.csv` file.